# Vertical Space Constraint Driving Subview Off Screen

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have added a vertical space constraint between a subview (Launch Box) and its container view:

[image]

Size inspector for the Launch Box:

[image]

Size inspector for the container view:

[image]

This is how the storyboard looks like in XCode:

[image]

But in the simulator the Launch Box is partially out of screen:

[image]

There are no other constraints.

Any ideas why the Launch Box would be pushed off screen like that?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I added height and width constraints to Launch Box:

[image]